# How does the satellite orbiting the Earth, first slows down to some extent, and speed up again to maintain the orbital motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, satellites

We consider that the satellite has time period equal to earth's rotational period, because of equal magnitude of orbital velocity, if that is so, it's at rest relative to earth's rotational motion which carries along the atmosphere at the same velocity so there must have been no air resistance being acted upon the geostationary satellite.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or how your question in the title relates to the text.

Comment: In context to geostationary satellites, they have velocity equal to the velocity of earth rotating about it's own axis and since earth holds the atmosphere it should too have velocity equal to that of earth while roatating. If it was so how can the geo stationary satellite have face any air resistance even if there is very lowly densed atmosphere at that height? For it to slow down?

Comment: Are you thinking of elliptical orbits?

Answer (score 2):

If the satellite rotates the earth in 24 hours, then it is in a so called geostationary  (or geosynchronous) orbit.  Such an orbit is circular and has an altitude of nearly 36,000 km above the equator.  There is very little atmosphere at that height.

More of an issue is the effects of lunar and solar gravity and the fact that the earth isn't an exact sphere.  To counter these effects, orbital corrections are required periodically.  The satellites have onboard propulsion systems to achieve this.